# Tag badges not being updated from Thu 19 to Fri 20?

Tags: bug, tag-badges

I just noticed that the "Tags" section in users' profile has not been updated last night at 3 am UTC.

No worries for that, just to know if people in the team are aware of it.

Comment: It will be updated once in a day. you have to wait.

Comment: Yes, it is updated every day at 3 am UTC, I think. But last 3 am it did not happen.

Comment: Where are you seeing that it wasn't updated?

Comment: @NickCraver Yesterday I had a score of 399 in [awk] tag http://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui I answered few questions and it is still showing 399. Also, if you compare data from http://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/topusers with real one, you see it shows 161 of my questions instead of 165 or 166.

Comment: Well you're not wrong, there was an issue with daily tasks last night - was just curious how you noticed :)  They'll run tonight, I hope

Comment: Thanks @NickCraver for the work!! :)

Comment: @NickCraver it worked. Thanks! If you post your comment as an answer I can accept it to show the issue is solved.

Comment: @NickCraver it looks like it hasn't run tonight.

Comment: @NickCraver neither last nights.